# Multivariable Limit Question-Arctan and ln

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can someone help me calculate :
$$\lim _{(x,y)\to (1,2)} \frac {\arctan(x+y-3)}{\ln(x+y-2)}?$$

I think substituting $x+y = t $ might help, but I am not sure that doing such a substitution in a multivariable case is legitimate, and I prefer not doing this.

Can you help me?

Thanks !

Comment: l'Hôpital's rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to take $t=(x-1)+(y-2)$. Then we obtain 
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\arctan{t}}{\ln(1+t)}=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,2)} \frac {\arctan(x+y-3)}{\ln(x+y-2)}=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (1,2)} \frac {\arctan((x-1)+(y-2))}{\ln((x-1)+(y-2))}=\\
=\left|\matrix{u=x-1\\
v=y-2} \right|=\lim\limits_{(u,\,v)\to (0,0)} \frac {\arctan(u+v)}{\ln(1+u+v)}=1$$ 
since both numerator and denominator depends only on sum $u+v.$